# Flowrouter - have to reload whole page for route to be recognised

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

Quite basic setup - user submits a post, it's inserted by a method, then user should be routed to a confirm page with the `_id` of the newly created post:

```
const onSubmitPost = (post) => {
      createPost.call(post, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
          instance.errorMessage.set(err.reason);
        } else {
          FlowRouter.go("create-post/:postId/confirm", { postId: res });
      }
   });
};

// Route definition    
FlowRouter.route("/create-post/:postId/confirm", {
  name: "create-confirm",
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render("MainPage", { content: "ConfirmPostContainer" });
  }
});
```

But when I try this, I get `There is no route for the path: create-post/abc123/confirm`

If I manually press reload, it works fine - no problems.

Anyone have any idea what's going on, and how to fix?

EDITS

- This is called on the `/create-post` route - redirect to confirm the
  post after it's created
- Added route definition
- Tried using `redirect` instead of `go` - no difference

Comment: can you show the definition for the `create-post` route? and also what is the route you're on when you call the method?

Comment: @tomsp done! It's called from the base `create-post` route. And I know many many many people have a problem with FR initialisation where there's no route for the path "/", but all my other routes do seem to work just fine.

Comment: I'm going through all packages now to see if there's somehow a conflict with another package using an older version of FlowRouter, but this seems quite unlikely to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things I can suggest you to try. My hunch is that the problem stems from calling the `.go` method from `/create-post` with a relative path.

So, first, try route-names instead: `FlowRouter.go('create-confirm', { postId: res });`

Second, try absolute paths: `FlowRouter.go('/create-post/' + res + '/confirm');` - notice the leading slash `/` !

Does that work?

Comment: Wow - *both* of those approaches work. Which is very odd as that didn't work when using `redirect`. Makes no sense to me that this should happen as the two routes render different container templates. But thanks - wish I could give two upvotes for two solutions!

Answer (score 0):

try FlowRouter.redirect(YOUR ROUTE NAME , { postId: res }

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. `redirect` actually takes a URL so had to do `FlowRouter.redirect(`create-league/${res}/confirm`);` but same error message in the console - no route for the path...

Comment: sorry my mistake 
 FlowRouter.redirect(YOUR ROUTE NAME , { postId: res })

Comment: any idea why this happens?